# Prove function is Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration

Let $f: [0;1] \to \mathbb R$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x = 0 \\
                       \dfrac{1}{x}-\left[\dfrac{1}{x}\right] & \text {otherwise}
                     \end{cases}$$
Prove that f is Riemann integrable.
I have a solution in my textbook however i dont understand it. Could anyone explain intuition why such partiton was chosen? Why right after $U(P,f)-L(P,f)$ we have $\frac{1}{n_0+1}$?

Solution:
Let $\varepsilon>0$, there exist natural number $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$ for all $n>n_0$> Let P be partition such that:

$0=x_0<x_1=\dfrac{1}{n_0+1}<x_2< \dots <x_{n'_0}=\dfrac{1}{n_0}<x_{n'_0+1}< \dots <x_{n'_1}=\dfrac{1}{n_0-1}< \dots <x_{n'_{n_0-1}}=1$

and $x_i-x_{i-1}<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{4n_0}$ for $i \geq 2$.

Then:
$$U(P,f)-L(P,f)=\frac{1}{n_0+1}+\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n'_{0}}(M_i-m_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n_0-2}\sum\limits_{i=n'_k+1}^{n'_{k+1}}(M_i-m_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+2n_0\frac{\varepsilon}{4n_0}=\varepsilon$$ So $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: You might want to put in an explanation for what $\left[\dfrac 1 x\right]$ means. It's not obvious. Is it the floor function?

Comment: @PrimeMover It is a notation to write $[x]$ for the integer part and $\{x\}$ for the fractional part

Comment: @FShrike Floor function then. thx. Worth explaining the notation in the question. Then again, in that case $\dfrac 1 x - \left[\dfrac 1 x\right]$ can be directly replaced by $\left\{\dfrac 1 x\right\}$ amirite?

Comment: @PrimeMover Yeah that's how I've seen it used

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the chosen partition is that the map $f$ is

- continuous except at the points $\{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$. It means that around zero, the points of discontinuities is a converging sequence towards zero. Elsewhere the discontinuities are isolated points.
- bounded below by $0$ and above by $1$.

Base on those fact, you can take for the two first points of the partition zero itself and $1/(n_0+1)$. The difference between the upper sum and lower sum on such interval is less than $1/(n_0+1)$. Which can be as small as we want providing that $n_0$ is chosen large enough.

Comment: Okay I see why the part 1/(n_0+1) is smaller than epsilon/2, and  what happens at points of discontinuity, but i dont see what is going on in between for example between 1/(n_0+1) and 1/n_0, okay you said function is continous there so it is probably easy to get inequality since M_i-m_i is small but I dont see where its included in solution. How you prove that f is continous except at 1/n for n natural?

Comment: The only points of discontinuities of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ are the integers. Hence the discontinuity points of $f$ I mentioned. Also on any interval $(\delta, 1]$ with $\delta \gt 0$, $f$ is piecewise linear. Hence Riemann integrable.

Comment: +1 for the simple argument. I usually deal with Riemann integral in this manner: If the set $D$ of discontinuities of integrand is finite the integral exists, if not then check the derived set $D'$(set of limit points of $D$). If $D'$ is finite we are done again.